# TypeScript generic accepting a function with callback last argument

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm having a problem applying my generics to a TypeScript definition.

The definitions are:

```
export function readFile(path: PathLike | number, options: { encoding?: null; flag?: string; } | undefined | null, callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException, data: Buffer) => void): void;
export function readFile(path: PathLike | number, options: { encoding: string; flag?: string; } | string, callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException, data: string) => void): void;
export function readFile(path: PathLike | number, options: { encoding?: string | null; flag?: string; } | string | undefined | null, callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException, data: string | Buffer) => void): void;

export function readFile(path: PathLike | number, callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException, data: Buffer) => void): void;
```

As you can see they accept 2 to 3 arguments, and the last one is always a callback.

Now my generic is:

```
function cbCall<Ret, Arg1, Arg2>(
    fun: (arg1: Arg1, arg2: Arg2, cb: (error: any, result: Ret) => any) => any,
    obj: any,
    arg1: Arg1,
    arg2: Arg2
): Context<Ret>;
```

Since it expects a function with 3 arguments (last one being the callback) I would guess it would match one of the first 3 definitions. However, when I try to use `cbCall` like this:

```
CL.cbCall(
    fs.readFile,
    fs,
    'filename',
    { encoding: 'utf-8' }
);
```

I get the error:

```
Argument of type '{ encoding: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: ErrnoException, data: Buffer) => void'.
```

So somehow it expects `arg2` to be what `cb` is supposed to be.

If I remove the `Arg2` template parameter and replace it with `object`, it works, but this is not generic enough for my use case.

Please explain why that happens and whether I can achieve what I'm trying to achieve.

Edit: using `cbCall<string, string, object>(...)` works too, but again, defeats the purpose.

---

Edit: I simplified the example to this:

```
function fun(arg: string, cb: (err: string, res: string) => void);
function fun(cb: (err: string, res: string) => void): void;
function fun(arg: any, cb?: any): void {
    // noop
}

function call<Ret, Arg>(fun: (arg: Arg, cb: (err: string, res: Ret) => void) => any, arg: Arg) {
    // noop
}

// this works
call<string, string>(fun,'test');

// Argument of type '"test"' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: string, res: string) => void'.
call(fun,'test'); //
```

Changing the order of the first two lines also fixes it.
But shouldn't the first matching declaration be used and not the last?

Comment: Dropping a link here in case I don't have time to finish this answer: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3117-type-inference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type-parameter assignment takes place before overload resolution and doesn't backtrack on failures, so sometimes you get errors that could be avoided by choosing a different overload. I have yet to find a good explanation of the type-parameter matching algorithm, but this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16867) explains it a bit.

Since your `fun` has one overload, the last overload of `readFile` will get selected, as it is assumed to be the least-specific one. As a workaround for the type error, you can provide the desired overload yourself in the module where you call `cbCall`:

```
declare module 'fs' {
  function readFile(path: fs.PathLike | number, options: { encoding?: string | null; flag?: string; } | string | undefined | null, callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException, data: string | Buffer) => void): void;
}
```

It's still not great though. I myself have grown a little more conservative with generics after crashing the type checker ([issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16328)). Intricate solutions that work in one release often break in the next, and there are quite a few open issues that don't see much progress. Hopefully it will get more stable in the future.

EDIT: Just thought of another option. If the callback functions you pass to `cbCall` all share a last overload without the `options` argument, you could also add that overload to the type of `fun`:

```
interface CallbackFun<Arg1, Arg2, Ret> {
  (arg1 : Arg1, arg2 : Arg2, cb : (error : any, result : Ret) => any) : any
  (arg1 : Arg1, cb : (error : any, result : Ret) => any) : any
}
```

and use `fun: CallbackFun<Arg1, Arg2, Ret>` in the definition of `cbCall`.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. "the last overload of readFile will get selected, as it is assumed to be the least-specific one" - that did not occur to me, I guess it does make sense. I've decided to just explicitly pass template arguments in this case, that's least likely to break I think.